# Codeception with Yii1 enabled module

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii, functional-testing, codeception

I am using codeception 2.2.5 aand Yii 1.1.4
I have the issue with the Yii1 module. I have it configured for functional and unit tests

Here is the functional.suite.yml

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Yii1:
            appPath: 'www/test.php'
            url: 'http://localhost/test.php'
            part: init
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://localhost/index-test.php'
        - \Helper\Functional
coverage:
    enabled: true
    remote: false
```

Here is the unit.suite.yml

```
class_name: UnitTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Asserts
        - Yii1:
            appPath: 'www/test.php'
            url: 'http://localhost/test.php'
        - \Helper\Unit
```

When I run the tests separately everything works great. e.g.

```
php codecept.phar run functional --xml --html
php codecept.phar run unit --xml --html
```

When I run all together

```
php codecept.phar run --xml --html
```

It runs the functional without the issue connected with the Yii1 module. And on the unit it brings

```
[Codeception\Exception\ModuleConfigException]                     
  Yii1 module is not configured!                                    

  Couldn't load application config file www/test.php                
  Please provide application bootstrap file configured for testing
```

The main goal to run all together is the code coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my problem:

I created a separate module Yii1Ext(Yii1Ext.php) which extends to Yii1 module:

```
namespace Helper;

use Codeception\Module\Yii1;

class Yii1Ext extends Yii1
{
    public function _initialize()
    {
        $this->config['appPath'] = FRONTEND.'/'.$this->config['appPath'];
        parent::_initialize();
    }
}
```

And in configuration files have the Yii1Ext module enabled instead of Yii1 module

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Yii1Ext:
            appPath: 'www/test.php'
            url: 'http://localhost/test.php'
            part: init
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://localhost/'
```

Note: Make sure all defined variables in Yii are defined by the statement

```
defined('ROOT_DIR') or define('ROOT_DIR', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../'));
```